# Greensock - Snap to grid without Throwprops

Tags: javascript, gsap

Hello im trying to find a way to get the snap property of draggable for Greensock to work without throwprops or livesnap. I would like when you let go of the '.face' for it to snap to the closest spot. It works with livesnap but I don't want to have the jagged dragging of it.

Here is what i'm working with at the moment:

```
    var droppables = $('.face');
    var choice = $('.choice');
    var gridWidth = 192;
    var gridHeight = 256;
    var overlapThreshold = '50%'; 

    function onDrop(dragged, dropped) {
      TweenMax.fromTo(dropped, 0.2, {opacity:1}, {opacity:0.5, repeat:1, yoyo:true});
    }

    Draggable.create(droppables, {
        type:'x,y',
        bounds:$('.content'),
        liveSnap:true,
        snap: {
            x: function(endValue) {
                return Math.round(endValue / gridWidth) * gridWidth;
            },
            y: function(endValue) {
                return Math.round(endValue / gridHeight) * gridHeight;
            }
        },
        onDrag: function(e) {
            var i = droppables.length;
            while (--i > -1) {
                if (this.hitTest(choice[i], overlapThreshold)) {
                    $(droppables[i]).addClass('highlight');
                } else {
                    $(droppables[i]).removeClass('highlight');
                }
            }
        },
        onDragEnd:function(e) {
            var i = droppables.length;
            while (--i > -1) {
                if (this.hitTest(choice[i], overlapThreshold)) {

                    onDrop(this.target, choice[i]);

                }
            }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is change your conditional logic in the onDragEnd callback and remove everything related to the snap event.

```
Draggable.create(droppables, {
    type:'x,y',
    bounds:$('.content'),
    onDrag: function(e) {
        var i = droppables.length;
        for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (this.hitTest(choice[j], overlapThreshold)) {
                $(droppables[j]).addClass('highlight');
            } else {
                $(droppables[j]).removeClass('highlight');
            }
        }
    },
    onDragEnd:function(e) {
        var i = droppables.length,
            snappedEl = false,
            originalOffset = $(this.target).offset();

        for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (this.hitTest(choice[i], overlapThreshold)) {

                var targetOffset = $(choice[j]).offset();

                onDrop(this.target, choice[i]);

                snappedEl = true;

                $(this.target).addClass("snapped");

                TweenLite.to(this.target, 0.1,{
                  x:targetOffset.left-originalOffset.left,
                  y:targetOffset.top-originalOffset.top
                });
            }
        }
        if(!snappedEl) {
          TweenLite.to(this.target, 0.2, {x:0, y:0});
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I set up a live sample here:

http://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/e2502a90f4ed69fef0e1e7b8d9c17aae

Also for this type of questions is far better for users to go straight to the GreenSock forums, you'll get a faster and official answer. Not that there's something wrong with coming here for answers, but the GreenSock forums are dedicated to GSAP and you'll get official support from the moderating team that includes the creator of the engine.

Cheers!!